# How to identify the next different value in a pandas column

Tags: pandas, iteration

I have created a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
ds = {"col1":[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

    col1
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      2
5      3
6      4
7      4
8      4
9      4
10     4
11     5
12     4
13     4
14     5
15     6
```

I need to calculate a new dataframe column (called `col2`) which contains the *next* value from `col1` which is different than the current value.

Example.

Let's take a look at row 0.
The value in `col1` is 1.
What is the next value in `col1` that is different than 1? It is the value 2 (at `row 4`).

Let's now take a look at row 1.
The value in col1 is 1.
What is the next value in `col1` that is different than 1? It is the value 2 (at `row 4`).

And so on.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

[image]

What is the python code to produce such dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the masked values up, and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
# identify the first value of each stretch
m = df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())
# mask the other, shift up, backfill
df['col2'] = df['col1'].where(m).shift(-1).bfill()
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
0      1   2.0
1      1   2.0
2      1   2.0
3      1   2.0
4      2   3.0
5      3   4.0
6      4   5.0
7      4   5.0
8      4   5.0
9      4   5.0
10     4   5.0
11     5   4.0
12     4   5.0
13     4   5.0
14     5   6.0
15     6   NaN
```

Intermediates to understand the logic;

```
    col1  col2      m  where(m)  shift(-1)
0      1   2.0   True       1.0        NaN
1      1   2.0  False       NaN        NaN
2      1   2.0  False       NaN        NaN
3      1   2.0  False       NaN        2.0
4      2   3.0   True       2.0        3.0
5      3   4.0   True       3.0        4.0
6      4   5.0   True       4.0        NaN
7      4   5.0  False       NaN        NaN
8      4   5.0  False       NaN        NaN
9      4   5.0  False       NaN        NaN
10     4   5.0  False       NaN        5.0
11     5   4.0   True       5.0        4.0
12     4   5.0   True       4.0        NaN
13     4   5.0  False       NaN        5.0
14     5   6.0   True       5.0        6.0
15     6   NaN   True       6.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
s = df['col1'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

s.map(df.groupby(s)['col1'].first().shift(-1))
```

Output:

```
0     2.0
1     2.0
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     3.0
5     4.0
6     5.0
7     5.0
8     5.0
9     5.0
10    5.0
11    4.0
12    5.0
13    5.0
14    6.0
15    NaN
```